# Extend a nested SCSS selector

Tags: sass

I'm trying to extend a nested class. Currently, I have this…

```
.button {
 styles

 &.primary {
  styles
 }
}

input[type="submit"] {
  @extend .button;
}
```

This works fine; however, my problem is that I want to use the `&.primary` on my input.

```
input[type="submit"] {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .primary; // doesn't work
  @extend .button.primary; // doesn't work
}
```

Is it possible to extend a nested SCSS selector?

Comment: @extend .button{@extend .primary}; have you try this?

Comment: It will already compile both `.button, input[type=submit]` and `.button.primary, input.primary[type=submit]`. Isn't it what you want?